# Creating Column in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have a problem in creating a datagrid column in c#

here is my code.

```
DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
newCol.HeaderText = txtHeader.Text;
newCol.Width = Convert.ToInt16(cboWidth.Text);
dgWorkArea.Columns.Add(newCol);
```

On my above code snippet, the error's came when trying to call the fourth (4th) line code. Here is the error.

*At least one of the datagridview control's columns has no cell template*

Can anyone help me on how can I create a simple column in datagrid.

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

`DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn`

I think you wont need any template after this

You can also go for check box type column or any other type. All available options are listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn

there are different type of columns:
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn, DataGridViewLinkColumn, etc.

You need somethis like this:

`DataGridViewColumn newCol = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();`

in first row